# Force PHP to outline errors using command line

Tags: php, ssh, execute

I'm trying to debug a PHP application that is running from the command line. I want to use a cronjob later on to invoke the module every hour.

For debugging I execute the PHP script like this:

```
php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/module/test/autostart/start.php 12 &
```

(forget about the „12“ - it's a parameter for the script)

Now basically I get this output via SSH:

```
[2] 10181
[1] Done                php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/module/test/autostart/start.php 12
```

I have no idea what I have changed but a few weeks ago I got the actual php errors directly on the screen. That's what I expect. But I don't know how to force PHP to output me the result directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use & at the end, command is started in background. You can see background processes by command `jobs`. When you try it, you can see php process in 'stopped' state.

Problem is that php is waiting for input.
It is caused by this php extension:

[readline php extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.readline.php)

Run it this way:

```
php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/module/test/autostart/start.php 12 < /dev/null &
```

or disable that extension.

Answer (score 2):

You won't see any output because you are running the script with an "&", you [fg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fg_%28Unix%29) command to bring back the process to the foreground.

Comment: Quoting from comment to previous answer: _No, that shouldn't be the reason. Even when in background, the output is still piped to stdout/stderr…_

Comment: Thank you guys!

I solved the problem with this command line:

    php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/module/test/autostart/start.php 12 >log.txt &

Answer (score 0):

drop the ampersand from the end of the commandline.  it tells the shell to run the command in the background.

edit: otherwise, it could be because you're using the web-tuned php.ini: i would expect that configuration to log errors into a logfile.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be the reason. Even when in background, the output is still piped to stdout/stderr…